# Convert a datetime into human understandable form

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

There is one class in laravel named `Carbon` and it is used to format dates into what they call as `diffForHumans()`. So, I have a date that looks like this:

```
2018-07-15 17:03:19
```

So, How do I convert it into `diffForHumans`? Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried so far to combat this so unique problem?

Comment: A lot of things, nothing quite helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
$date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse("2018-07-15 17:03:19")->diffForHumans();
```

Seriously? I get downvoted for answering his question?

Comment: You're welcome. Kindly accept this as the answer if you would.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you use Laravel I take it you use Twig. You could show the date like `{{ yourDate |date("m/d/Y") }}` where `yourDate` is the variable of your date. Read more [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/date.html).